# Regex: capture everything until specific word(s)

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have two variations of a string something like :

> The Student's Companion ***Author: Alcock, Pete;May, Margaret;Wright, Sharon***MIL EAN/ISBN: 9781283333115
>
> Java Programming: Java Expert***Author:Sarang, Poornachandra***MIL EAN/ISBN: 9781280117268

Now, I want to grab the first Author: Alcock, Pete aand Saran, Pooranachandra.

Now in Javascript, I am trying to do :

```
var regex = new RegExp("(Author:)\\s(.+)(?=;|MIL)");
var regexVal = value.match(regex);
console.log(regexVal);
```

OR

```
var regex = new RegExp("(Author:)\\s(.+)(?=MIL)");
var regexVal = value.match(regex);
console.log(regexVal);
```

Second Regex works perfectly fine if there is one Author, however, in case of multiple author, I want to pick value until first **;** not **MIL**

**|** matched either part, so, shouldn't it stop when first ; is found?

Regards,
Ravish

Comment: If the second one is otherwise working for you, try excluding `;` from `(.+)` with the `^` operator.

Comment: note that stackoverflow comments can also be upvoted just like answers, if you want to express value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
var regex = /Author:\s([^;*]+)/;
```

Or if those `*` aren't in the string:

```
var regex = /Author:\s((?:(?!MIL)[^;])+)/;
```

or

```
var regex = /Author:\s([^;])+?)(?=;|MIL)/;
```

Comment: @Ravish Answers can be accepted, if you want to express their value and thank authors.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem by modifying the regex to :

```
(Author:)(([^;])+)(;|MIL)
```

This regex says : should begin with "Author:" neget the ; and should end with ; or MIL.

Thanks